# Django: Handling DoesNotExist in a ListView

Tags: django

I have a custom query inside a `ListView` that returns all `Sites` that belong to the `Company` that the logged in User belongs to. The problem is that if the `User` has been created but no `Sites` belong to the `Company`, I get DoesNotExist error. I would like it to load a template that has an Add Site button.

models.py

```
class Company(models.Model):
    ...

class Site(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
```

views.py

```
class SiteList(ListView):
    model = Site
    paginate_by = 25

    def get_queryset(self):
        p = UserProfile.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)
        return Site.objects.filter(company=p.company)
```

Comment: I do not think the error is thrown due to Sites being non existent. It is due to UserProfile object that does not exist. Is the UserProfile model created as soon as the User model is created? Site.objects.filter() would return 'None' if there are no Sites belonging to a Company.

Comment: @gZing Site.objects.filter() would return [] if there are no Sites belonging to a Company

Comment: yes @ofnowhereland, Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can modify your view file as following:

```
   from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
   class SiteList(ListView):
       model = Site
       paginate_by = 25

       def get_queryset(self):
          try:
              p = UserProfile.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)
              return Site.objects.filter(company=p.company)
          except ObjectDoesNotExist:
              # code to add
```

Answer (score 0):

Model.objects.get() returns DoesNotExist error if no object is found.
You can do one of these:

```
class SiteList(ListView):
    model = Site
    paginate_by = 25

    def get_queryset(self):
        try:
            p = UserProfile.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)
        except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
            #do something here
        return Site.objects.filter(company=p.company)
```

or

```
class SiteList(ListView):
    model = Site
    paginate_by = 25

    def get_queryset(self):
        p = UserProfile.objects.filter(id=self.request.user.id)
        if len(p) == 0:
          #do something
        else:
          # do something else
        return Site.objects.filter(company=p[0].company)
```

Note: .filter does not throw an error, it will simply return an empty list

Comment: In second example You cannot use `p.company`, because p is a list. Use `p[0].company`.

Comment: @TomaszJakubRup fixed